# Creating a table in a module that contains a structure

Tags: vb.net

How do I create an array of ten that contains a public structure? And a module that contains that array? I have this so far but the structure wont let my array have a number between the parentheses.

```vb
Module Module 1
    Public Structure Élève
        Dim Nom As String
        Dim Prénom As String
        Dim Note As Integer
        Dim Rendement As Integer
        Dim TabÉlève() As Élève
    End Structure
End Module
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are meaning you want to have an array of your structure as a property of that structure?

Comment: Yes i want the array to be a property of that structure

Comment: Yeah I’m not sure that type of cyclical relationship is going to work.  Or it seems incredibly odd at least.

Comment: You realize that if you could do that, each instance of that struct would consume infinite amount of memory?